# ionic array and realtime firebase database

Tags: arrays, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to splice a specific item from an array and add the splice data to another parent node in the firebase realtime database. However when I push the data to the firebase realtime database, I want to remove the '0' and get the data to be added directly to 'MOW....'.

[image]

```
this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(se =>  {
          this.deletedData = this.Services.rewards.splice(data, 1)
          console.log(this.deletedData)
          const usedRewards = firebase.database().ref('usedrewards/').child(se.uid)
          usedRewards.push(this.deletedData)

        })
```

I have attached the codes here. Is there something I am doing wrong?

EDIT:
I have attached the service page codes here
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do ` this.Services.rewards` and `data` look like?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hello, I have attached the codes for the this.service.reward and `data` is selecting the item in the array

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.